# Search Wordpress Magic Fields items? No search results

Tags: php, wordpress, search, taxonomy

I have built a wordpress site that uses [magic fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/magic-fields/) almost exclusively (rather than default posts etc).

However, I am now trying to implement search functionality and finding that wordpress is not able to find any content that is created by Magic Fields.

I have altered my search to create a custom WP_Query, but am still not having any luck. For example, I have a post_type of 'project':

```
    $searchValue = $_GET['s'];

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'project',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_value' => $searchValue,
        'meta_key' => 'title'
    );

    $query = new WP_Query($args);
```

This returns no results. Where am I going wrong?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I too have had problems with magic field and the wordpress search.  The standard wordpress search only searches the post box content.  The way to handle searching through magic field content is to search the postmeta.

```
$add_value = true;
$query_array = array();
$query_for_posts = "page_id=";
$search_guery = $_GET['s'];
$search_results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."postmeta WHERE meta_value LIKE '%" . $search_guery ."%' ORDER BY post_id");

if(!empty($search_results))
{
    foreach ($search_results as $search_result) 
    {
        //loop through results
        for($i=0;$i<sizeof($query_array);$i++)
        {
            //check if post id in the array
            if($search_result->post_id == $query_array[$i])
                $add_value = false;
        }
        if($add_value)
        {
            //add the post id to the array if not a duplicate
            array_push($query_array, $search_result->post_id);
            //also add id for WP_Query
            $query_for_posts .= $search_result->post_id . ",";
        }
        $add_value = true;
    }
}
```

then to display the results.

```
if(!empty($query_array))
{
    for($i=0;$i<sizeof($query_array);$i++)
    {
        //get post from array of ids
        $post = get_page($query_array[$i]);
        //make sure the post is published
        if($post->post_status == 'publish')
            echo '<h3><a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'">'.$post->post_title.'</a></h3>';
    }
}
else
{
    //tell the user there are no results
}
```

you can also use the $query_for_posts variable in a WP_query.  It should have the value page_id=1,3,7,9,23... all the post ids from the search results.